# jQuery Plugin jCarousel Customization

Tags: jquery, css, jcarousel

Is there a way to customize jCarousel center the initial object?

And also I want previous and next slide to be half shown like this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/nori2tae/BGwYM/
＃I used moving boxes jquery plugin for the sample above by the way.

Any comment, suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanx for stopping by.

Comment: can you please link the jCarousel plugin page?

Comment: Sample Page: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html
jCarousel JS: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js